# Navigate to my store in Store app in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i want to add a button to my xaml page which will navigate to my store in store app, something like :

```
private void hotGame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // code go here
    }
```

and my store link looks like this

```
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/store/publishers?publisherId=GameXP%2BStudio&appId=a18e8dec-e69b-414d-9cb5-80c5a264d8eb
```

i just don't know if WP8 can navigate to another app (in this case is Store app) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply invoke a `WebBrowserTask`..

```
    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/store/publishers?publisherId=GameXP%2BStudio&appId=a18e8dec-e69b-414d-9cb5-80c5a264d8eb
", UriKind.Absolute);
    webBrowserTask.Show();
```

OR the `MarketPlaceDetailsTask`..

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "a18e8dec-e69b-414d-9cb5-80c5a264d8eb";
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

Comment: ah yes, i used MarketplaceDetailTask, but it only navigated to just 1 of my app (not my store link which listed all my app) , So i think WebBrowserTask is the best solution , thank you :D